# Failed to instantiate view controller. - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

So, I'm trying to instantiate my view controller programmatically using storyboard references.

I've put this code in the AppDelegate:

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialController: WelcomePageViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomePageViewController") as! UITabBarController
        window?.rootViewController = initialController        
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

And set this inside my view controller's storyboard:

[image]

However when I run the application, only a black screen is shown and this message:
"Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?"

I've used this exact code in other apps and it works just fine.

I've tried to clean build folder, to run it on an actual device and to create and instantiate a different storyboard file but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you also have a `SceneDelegate`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, there is a SceneDelegate. However I have not implemented any of its functions. The file is as default.

Comment: You Can set it programmatically like this UITabBarController().viewControllers = [UIViewController()]. The First view controller in array will be your initial view controller

Comment: @umerfarooqi still black screen and error: "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?"

Comment: @ShadiHabiballah -- *"Yes, there is a SceneDelegate."* -- you have to do this from `SceneDelegate.swift`, ***not*** from `AppDelegate.swift`. Also, make sure you have deleted "Main" from the "Main Interface" field / dropdown in your project settings.

Comment: you have to set ''initialController"  instead of UIViewController(), can you share the updated code here?

Answer (score 0):

Open your `Main.storyboard` file and find `WelcomePageViewController`. When it’s selected, go to the attributes inspector and check the box marked `Is Initial View Controller`.

You should see a right-facing arrow appear to the left of `WelcomePageViewController`, showing that it’s your storyboard’s entry point.

Now you're all set to go!!!

[image: this is how is will look like <code>Is Initial View Controller</code>]

Comment: I need to set the initial controller programatically from the AppDelegate. As I need to select which will be the initial view controller depending on a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So i think here is something you can do if it suits:

- set entry point to the navigation controller
- class that navigation controller with a file like `rootNavigationVC.swift` which is subclass of `UINavigationController`
- now in `didLoad()` you can set it's `viewController` or push one based on your condition

trust me its better than coding in `AppDelegate.swift` which never worked for me.